# Im getting an error :expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: django

```
#my views files
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from datetime import datetime
from home.models import Contact
```

#When my form is submitted with post method it goes in contact function and i am getting error 'expected string or bytes-like object'

```
# Create your views here.

def contact(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        name=request.POST['name']
        email=request.POST['email']
        phone=request.POST['phone']
        desc=request.POST['desc']
        contact = Contact(name=name,email=email,phone=phone,desc=desc,date=datetime.today)
        contact.save()
    return render(request,'contact.html')
```

Models file for creating table and here i didnot got an issues.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Contact(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=122)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=122)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=12)
    desc=models.TextField()
    date=models.DateTimeField()
```

Comment: Did you applied migrations? ```python manage.py makemigrations``` and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: i left using parenthiesis in .date=datetime.today. so I got error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
contact = Contact(...date=datetime.today)
```

Change `date=datetime.today` to `date=datetime.today()` (you need the `()`). Otherwise you are passing the function instead of the output of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        name=request.POST['name']
        email=request.POST['email']
        phone=request.POST['phone']
        desc=request.POST['desc']
        contact = Contact(name=name,email=email,phone=phone,desc=desc,date=datetime.date.today())
        contact.save()
    return render(request,'contact.html')
```

Or better way to add times automatically for first insert you can use: **auto_now_add=True** in *DateTimeField*.

```
from django.db import models

class Contact(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=122)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=122)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=12)
    desc=models.TextField()
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

If you add *auto_now_add*, then you don't have to add datetime manually:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        name=request.POST['name']
        email=request.POST['email']
        phone=request.POST['phone']
        desc=request.POST['desc']
        contact = Contact(name=name,email=email,phone=phone,desc=desc)
        contact.save()
    return render(request,'contact.html')
```

[Refs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add)